# KnockoutJS catch errors Binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to catch an error, correct it and continue executing the program.
http://jsfiddle.net/Gthv9/12/

But, I can't do it!

If you click on: "re Check On Model1", "re Check  On Model3" - it's ok.

If you click on: "re Check On Model1", "re Check  On Model2", "re Check  On Model3" - there's an error.

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: name3 is not defined;
Bindings value: text: name3
```

Why?

I wrapped the problem code in a try-catch block (viewModel.recheckData2() ),
but, the application crashes on clicking viewModel.recheckData3() !

I know that knockoutJS stores the error state (new model2()), but don't know what I should do.

How can I catch the error properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your exact goal, but Knockout will stop binding when it runs into this type of an issue.

If your issue is simply undefined variables, then one trick that you can use is to bind against `$data.name3` rather than just `name3`.  Accessing a undefined property off of a valid object does not cause an error.

If you really want something more robust, then you could consider using a [custom binding provider](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/09/ko-13-preview-part-2-custom-binding.html).

For example, you could write a quick wrapper to the real binding provider like:

```
var ErrorHandlingBindingProvider = function() {
    var original = new ko.bindingProvider(); 

    //determine if an element has any bindings
    this.nodeHasBindings = original.nodeHasBindings;

    //return the bindings given a node and the bindingContext
    this.getBindings = function(node, bindingContext) {
        var result;
        try {
            result = original.getBindings(node, bindingContext);
        }
        catch (e) {
            if (console && console.log) {
                console.log("Error in binding: " + e.message);   
            }
        }

        return result;
    };
};

ko.bindingProvider.instance = new ErrorHandlingBindingProvider();
```

This would catch errors, log them, and proceed.  Of course the element that had this "bad" binding would not bound.  If there is some known way that you want to handle it, then you could add that logic after catching the error.  Maybe you want to inspect that element (node) and the bindingContext to determine what needs to be done.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/KxXqs/

UPDATE: Here is a version for 3.0+ that traps/logs errors in binding syntax as well as errors when the bound value is actually evaluated. http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ecbn1dmy/

Comment: @RP Niemeyer "Accessing a undefined property off of a valid object does not cause an error" - I've assigned a function to the name property of a template binding. If the function returns undefined, I get the kind of uncatchable error the questioner is talking about whether I use $root or $ data or just the function name. Would using `computed` help in that case?

Comment: @DavidHyogo - do you have a jsFiddle or some sample code? Sounds like maybe something else is going on.

Comment: @RPNiemeyer http://jsfiddle.net/DavidHyogo/Ak4gE/ reproduces what I mean. useTemplate returns undefined and Knockout sends an error like "TypeError: b is undefined" to the console in Firebug whether I use $root.useTemplate, $data.useTemplate or just the function name. Of course, when useTemplate returns "alternative", the correct template is displayed. If I wrap the function in a ko.computed, I get "Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters."

Comment: I see. Your error is actually within the template binding, as it is not expecting the name to be specified but undefined. Do you have a certain scenario where you are not able to return a valid template name?  A computed won't do the trick in this case, because it would still need to return a valid template and Knockout expects a function where the first argument is the current data item (important when using with `foreach`). This is where your computed error is coming from.

Comment: I think I can sympathise with the questioner here, that as my application grows, I end up with convoluted code that returns undefined when I least expect it and a Knockout binding error tends not to be informative. So the "certain scenario" is my bad code. At least I am now writing more defensively to ensure that the `useTemplate` function always returns a valid string.

Comment: $root.varName solved my issue :) (which was load/parse order in my code!)

Comment: @RP Niemeyer , You are truely genius.

Comment: how to use this in froeach binding..go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142243/how-to-fix-undefined-property-error-in-knockoutjs

Comment: For some reason I havent been able to determine, this approach has unintended side effects in knockout 3.2 : It causes all bindings to be evaluated twice (which can have huge performance and behavior consequences).  http://jsfiddle.net/38qowkey/

Comment: @ShaunRowan - the bindingProvider interface changed slightly in 3.0 to use `getBindingAccessors`, although `getBindings` is still supported it can have that type of side effect depending on the code run. Here is a version that works with 3.0+ that traps both syntax errors as well as errors in the actual binding value when it is evaluated: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ecbn1dmy/

Answer (score 1):

I added another line to the error handler from @RPNiemeyer to console the node causing the error in the catch block - makes it really easy to find an error on a complex page:

```
if (console && console.log) {
            console.log("Error in binding: " + e.message);
            console.log("Node causing error:");
            console.log(node);
        }
```