# How to fix undefined property error in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

> Most of the time i get some error for 'undefined' property in knockout. I found a solution for the same on [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136678/knockoutjs-catch-errors-binding). It is effective for simple binding, but my question is that how would i use this technique for 'foreach' binding like i have tried like

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/gCHEz/)

> below code is not working

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: model.mappings">
    <tr>
     <td>
    <select data-bind="options:mappings.variableList, optionsText:'Key',optionsValue:'Value', value:mappings.selectedVariable>
    </select>
   </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

> But below code is working

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:mappings">
    <tr>
     <td>
    <select data-bind="options:variableList, optionsText:'Key',optionsValue:'Value', value:selectedVariable>
    </select>
   </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

> Js for both is same like:

```
var list = //some array
var arr =// [{variableList : list}];

var model={
mappings:ko.observableArray(arr)
}

ko.applyBindings......
```

Comment: so should i use like-  <select data-bind="options:model.mappings.variableList" >  ?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your "model" being a function. When binding in html, you are able to access only local variables of model. Model itself is not visible because that is out of your scope. Mappings is a variable in model and that's why you can access it by just writing `foreach: mappings`. `model` is not part of model, it is model... Hope this helps.

Also, when you write `foreach: mappings` then you kind-of enter a foreach loop so that is why you don't write `mappings.PropertyName` and instead just write `PropertyName`

edit: my comment on your post was completely wrong so I deleted it

Comment: i am trying to catch binding error, assume the situation when there is 'mappings' exists inside model but no 'variableList' inside 'mappings', then it will throw error, how to handle it?